# Preloading HTML5 videos on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm looking for a solution where:

4 MP4s/video files, each 5MBs size.

Those videos will be played one by one like single MP4/video file (without gaps between MP4 files) cross browser and cross device.

Do you know what would the best approach for this, I'm not looking for solution where video source files would be replaced. (as there'll be always gap) With what I come so far is having 2 separate video elements, where in one video will be preloaded while another one is playing, though on majority of mobile devices preload attribute isn't supported.

any answers greatly appreciated,
Adam

Comment: Preloading large files on mobile is usually a bad idea, because mobile users dislike having their data plans chewed up for no good reason. That said, your best solution would probably be to [merge the videos into a single file server-side](http://superuser.com/questions/709656/ffmpeg-joining-2-videos-to-play-one-after-another).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that most browsers will disallow you from doing this for @Blazemonger's reason.

Comment: Thanks @Blazemonger, that's what I thought, are you aware of any solution that would work without having interfering into server side? Would there be any JS solution that could buffer video files into one mp4 and stream it? probably HTML request headers would have to be amended slightly in order to make it to work

Comment: These are very small video files. Pre-loading should NOT be an issue. It would be the equivalent of putting 5 5MB images on a page. The question is if you put 5 5MB images on a page would the phone crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an elegant solution but it will work for your idea of loading in multiple instances of the video tag.

In HTML put 5 video players.

In CSS hide 4 of them (display:none);

In JS
make a global var array of the video objects

```
var v=new Array;
v[1] = document.getElementById('player1');
...
v[5] = document.getElementById('player5');
```

On players 1-4 add event listeners for the "end" event which calls a next function.

```
next function(n){
  v[n+].style.display='block';
  v[n].style.display='none';
  v[n+1].play()
}
```

}

Comment: You may need to add v[x].load() for the players. You want to make sure only the first player is loading.  Then at the onload event load the other players.  They can load simultaneously on a desktop phones, whatever the carrier allows.